# Issue on Using Google Rich Snippet

Tags: seo, google-search, google-rich-snippets

I have received some reviews from my clients about my daycare business via email  now I just wonder if I can use the Google Rich Snippet to add and display those on Google Search result without having them on Google+/ Google Maps Reviews!

I already tried

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review">
 <span itemprop="itemreviewed">Kiddies Palace Daycare</span>
   Reviewed by <span itemprop="reviewer">Sufi</span> on
  <time itemprop="dtreviewed" datetime="2015-10-13">2015-10-13</time>.
  <span itemprop="summary">This is a great daycare</span>
  <span itemprop="description">I must say when it comes to Day Care Center in North Vancouver, Kiddies Palace Daycare is one of the best places to leave you child assured that they will take care of your baby as one of their own.</span>
  Rating: <span itemprop="rating">4.5</span>
</div>
```

but I have like 10 reviews like this with different `itemprop="rating"` values , so how I can put the overall review on all of them? For example how I can fill required data like this (I am not even sure if they are required?!):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) instead of Data-Vocabulary.org (the latter is no longer maintained).

- If you want to provide multiple reviews, you need multiple [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review) items.
- If you want to provide the average rating, you need one [`AggregateRating`](http://schema.org/AggregateRating) item.

What Google will (or won’t) do with this markup is documented at https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews. (It might be that you won’t get a Review Rich Snippet if you have multiple reviews on the same page, but I don’t know about that. Such questions would be on-topic on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).)